# Is $B_1 \times B_2 \times ... \times B_n \times X \times X \times ...$ a base for the product topology?

Tags: general-topology

As the title asks,

> Is $B_1 \times B_2 \times ... \times B_n \times X \times X \times ...$ a base for the product topology?  (for all $B_n \in \tau$)

i.e. Can you assume that the open sets $B_n$ (that are not the whole space) occur in the first $n$ positions for some $n$.

Comment: You'd have to say what the product topology is on - presumably $X$ is a topological space with $\tau$ its topology, and the space you are curious about is the countably-infinite product of $X$ with itself?

Comment: Basically, this is true, if you state it carefully - you have to say a set is in this basis if it is for the form $B_1\times\cdots\times B_n\times X\times X\times\cdots$ *for some* $n$. That "for some" is crucial, because, for different elements of the basis, you'll need different $n$.

Comment: However, the proof of such theorems depends on the definition you have for the product topology, which can vary. There are two definitions that books/teachers use. One is that it is the smallest topology such that the maps $\pi_i:X^{\infty}\to X$ is continuous for all $X$. The other definition gives a specific basis that looks similar to the above, but slightly different.

Comment: Thank you Thomas.  I will be more careful stating all of the assumptions from now on also.

Comment: It would still help to know which definition of the product topology you are using. As I said, different books use different definitions, and the proofs are vastly different depending.

Comment: I was using the definition of base for the Tychonoff product topology, where a base looks like the above (title) except that the $B_n$ sets are not necessarily the first $n$ coordinates and can be quite scattered, but there are only finitely many such $B_n$ and the rest of the factors are required to be the whole space, $X$.

Comment: Since $B_i=X$ is allowed in your basis, just show this basis is exactly the Tychonoff basis.